# Algorithm for scaling image based on another image size and also preserve its aspect ratio

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, linear-algebra

I have 2 images, *Image 1* and *Image 2*.

*Image 1* has a size of 512(width) x 515(height).

Then *Image 2* with size of 256(width) x 256(height).

*Image 2* is will be used as a watermark and will be placed on top of *Image 1*.

I want *Image 2* size to be dependent on *Image 1* size. *Image 2* can resize up or down depending on the size of *Image 1*.

The new size(width & height) of *Image 2* should be *20* percent size of *Image 1* and the-same time preserve its aspect ratio.

What's the algorithm to find the new size(width & height) of *Image 2*?

Right now, I use  `(20%/100) * 512` to resize it, but this does not preserve *Image 2* aspect ratio.

Comment: 20% by area, or going by one of the axes, with the other axis re-sized to preserve the aspect ratio?

Comment: @samgak 20% by smaller than Image 1 in width and height. I can do this part. The problem now is the aspect ration which I want to also be the-same length apart after the scaling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the two images don't have the same aspect ratio then it's mathematically impossible to scale both width and height by 20% and preserve the aspect ratio.

So, chose an axis that you will use to scale by, and scale the other one to the size that preserves the aspect ratio.

e.g, using width:

```
new_image1_width = 512 * (20 / 100) = 102.4
```

Then compute the new height to preserve the aspect ratio:

```
original_aspect_ratio = image2_width / image2_height = 256 / 256 = 1
new_image1_height = 102.4 / original_aspect_ratio = 102.4
```

Or do it the other way (this time multiplying by the ratio):

```
new_image1_height = 515 * (20 / 100) = 103
original_aspect_ratio = image2_width / image2_height = 256 / 256 = 1
new_image1_width = 103 * original_aspect_ratio = 103
```

If you have to handle arbitrary image sizes and arbitrary scale factors, you will need two switch between the two ways depending on what you want the rule to be. E.g. you could always go with the smaller of the two, or use a ratio-adjusted height unless this gives you a height larger than image 1 height, and in that case use the second way, or vice versa.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that the image dimension were 512 * 515 and not 512 * 512. Have edited the answer

Comment: I am trying this and will let you know in minutes

Comment: Just to let you know that the second image is a watermark image that will be placed in front of the first image. It just has to be smaller by some percent and will be placed on the top right of side of the first image.The fact is that no one knows the size of both images. The number you see in this question is just for an example. The auto-rescale stuff and also maintaining its proportion is what I am struggling with. Just want to make sure that the re-sized image does not look so much different from the original one.